# Why are incsearch and hlsearch disabled when opening a .csv file?

Tags: vimrc, search, highlight

I like the incsearch and hlsearch options in Vim, so early on in my `.vimrc` file, I have the following lines:

```
augroup allfiles
    autocmd FileType * :set nocindent noexpandtab incsearch hlsearch
augroup END
```

For most file formats (e.g., any `.txt`, `.tex`, `.sql`, or `.pl` file, and for `.vimrc` itself), this works fine, but when I'm editing a `.csv` file (often exported by Excel, but not always), these options aren't on when I start Vim. I can manually enable them, but I usually forget until I've already started trying to search for something, and then I have to stop what I'm doing and enable those options.

I'm curious why they're disabled by default for this specific file type.

I have no `augroup` or `autocmd` lines in my `.vimrc` file that are specific to `.csv` files, so I don't think I'm disabling this later on in the config file.

In case it matters: I'm using version 8.1.3741 via Ubuntu on WSL2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event "FileType" is triggered after `:h 'filetype'` option is set for a buffer. And if it's not then, well, not.

The "csv" file type (detection only) was added just few days ago (v9.0.0049). So, no surprise it's not working on your setup.

You can update your Vim or just add this bit yourself, see `:h ftdetect`.

Comment: Nice and easy, thank you.